# Make the horizontal bars less prominent

Tags: discussion, design

The new design has very prominent 2px or 1px solid black horizontal lines separating questions and comments.

I personally find those bars distracting, and think they should be toned down significantly by making them gray and/or not solid.

As I was unsure if that was only personal preference I checked every SE site with a design on how the dividers between questions looked. *None* of the SE sites use a solid black line, they're always at least gray and most of the time they are dotted lines that are pretty understated.

Answer (score 0):

this has been changed to light grey.